# Angular 5 Http Post Using Where

Tags: angular, rest, loopback

I am using a Loopback backend REST API and an Angular 5 frontend. However, I am unable to get the post function to work - I consistently get the error "Value is not an object."

```
   this.http.post(url, {

      "displayName": user.displayName,
      "email": user.email,
      "uid": user.uid,
      "photoURL": user.photoURL,
      "phoneNumber": user.phoneNumber,
      "verifiedPhone": user.verifiedPhone

    }, {params: new HttpParams().set('where','uid=' + user.uid)}).subscribe( res => {
      console.log("results of updating user: ", res);
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the old Http service, or the new HttpClient service?

Comment: I am using the new HttpClient service.

Comment: On what line is the error, or is the error happening on the server?

Comment: It could be the 'uid=' equal sign. It is strange though, to have a query parameter on a post request.

Comment: I tried using %3D instead of =, but I get a 500 server error.

The error is in the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you use httpParams in a post your url change like

```
yoururl?variable=value
```

In your case you'll get

```
yoururl?where=uid=999
```

see [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request) You can not do this.

Comment: I have tried changing it out with %3D instead, but this gives me a 500 server error

Answer (score 0):

Plz use where Like:

```
let param = {
          where: { search: search },
          skip: 0,
          limit: 6
        }
   const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

this.http.post(url, param, { headers }).subscribe(response => {

  }, err => {
      });
```

Comment: you make remote method in backend? if so than provide code.